# Can I practice Buddhist practices as a hindu?

Tags: shiva

I'm a hindu that seeks to go to amitabha's pureland if I cannot make it to Lalita's abode Manidvipa,or just in the case that out of the two religions,I am wrong about hinduism being true.could I recite amitabha's name or make aspiration prayers,and would I be sinning?

from a Hindu perspective,thru various powers a buddhist master could create a pureland for followers.in
 hinduism we have gyaanganj too.with various shakti powers a yogi of any religion can create even universes as Vishwamitra the Rishi did when devaloka was denied him.

I love amitabha and padmasambhava,and though I agree more with Shaivite philosophy,I wouldnt mind being both a buddhist and a shaivite.in fact in the list of mahasiddhas in the Vajrayana tradition some of them were shaivites and dual shaivite vajrayana like matseyendranath(who was really the first person to institute kali worship after being initiated by yoginis at kamakhya)and his pupil Gorakshanath wich is revered by both buddhists and hindus as a great enlightened being.

my philosophy is actually shaivite,so maybe it would be dishonest to label myself buddhist,but buddhism(of the jonang self atmanic variety) could be true and I dont want to miss out on that possibility and Buddhas are great people with high realizations.I believe at the core Jonang buddhism and Shaivism are philosophically similar,and KalaCakra(jonang's Adibuddha) is said by some occultists to be Shiva(Mahaa kal) anyway.some call him a buddha others a deva,maybe he is both for different people.in the Skanda purana,Shiva says that he guides the buddhists to moksha and the path of the vedas thru their agamas,and in buddhism maheshwar is a yidam ,a wordly protector and a emanation of lokeshwara bodhisattva.

the Newars too practice both shaivite tantra and vajrayana tantra.The Dalai Lama loves and pays respects to Maheshwar and many yogis of the shaktah and shaiva traditions studied with buddhist yogis and compared notes.

like I said in reality my philosophy is Tirumular advaita shaiva/kashmir shaiva(its really the same thing) or Advaita shaktah(I havent decided who is greater shiva or devi)but Buddhism of the jonang school seems sound.if I'm wrong I can still go to eternal pureland if i practice aspirations .

Hope this question doesnt offend anybody.

would I be sinning if I make aspiration to go to sukhavati as a hindu?''just in case''?

Comment: If you are an Advaitin I say go for it, knock yourself out

Comment: thanks.Jonang is basically the same as Advaita shaivism.Dzogchen has some similarities too.